# Undefined variable inside laravel left join

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, anonymous-function

in my case, i want to display users and orders completed by each user, orders have status
i get $status from input form
here is my code

```
$orders = DB::table('user_profiles')
        ->leftJoin('orders', function($join){
            $join->on('user_profiles.id','=','orders.id_user')
                ->where('orders.status','=',$status);
        })
        ->selectRaw('user_profiles.*, count(orders.id_user) as order_try_count')
        ->groupBy('user_profiles.id')
        ->orderBy('order_try_count',$order)
        ->paginate(15);
```

but i get undefined variable status, what should i do to solve this problem ?, thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yoo need to pass variables into closure using `use` construction like so:

```
->leftJoin('orders', function($join) use ($status) {
```

instead of

```
->leftJoin('orders', function($join) {
```

Reference: [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Thanks dear, it worked in Laravel / Lumen 8 also. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `use()` method to user variable in closure

Try

```
->leftJoin('orders', function($join) use($status){
      $join->on('user_profiles.id','=','orders.id_user')
            ->where('orders.status','=',$status);
})
```